# Verifying text between <div> using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to verify whether specific slot on webpage is loaded or not. I am using Selenium WebDriver in `main()` function for that (should I use a JUnit test case?).

What are ways to retrieve text between any `<div>` having a specific id?

If given [this page](http://ideone.com/TK8Mk):

```html
<div id="center-2" class="promo">
    <div class="unified_widget rcmBody">
        <span class="logo"><img src="someimage.gif" /></span>
        <span class="headline">Make money by Selling items on Amazon</span>
        <span class="link"><a href="/content/sell-on-amazon.htm">Selling On Amazon</a></span>
        <span class="body">Sell your items on Amazon.com. Amazon can help you grow your business and reach more customers.</span>
        <div class="h_rule"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when `<div id = center-2>` is given, I need to extract

"Make money by Selling items on Amazon",
"Selling On Amazon",
"Sell your items on Amazon.com. Amazon can help you grow your business and reach more customers."

Which method should I use?

Comment: @Slanec : did you used any HTML beautifier to format above code ?
And I also face problem while pasting code snippet as every line has to be shifted by `4 space characters` , can we use some kind of tag for that like `[code] [/code]` ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has a function to format code, so I used that and then manually deleted the (hopefully) irrelevant parts. For code inserting to SO, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/184794).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure an element is loaded, use [Implicit and Explicit waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Usually, when you need to interact with the element, an implicit wait is enough. Once it's set, it's used for every element lookup. In my experience, it's enough for 95 % of cases.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you need some more advanced waiting (or just use the wait once), explicit wait is there for you.

---

There are three usually used ways to retrieve an element with a specific `id` I know about:

1. The preferred way:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("elemId"));
   ```
2. A good way if you need to begin with an element and then search its descendants:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#elemId"));
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('elemId')"));
   ```
3. The way a lot of people uses, because they're comfortable with XPath:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='elemId']"));
   ```

To know more about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#selectors) and [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), see any tutorial on the web.

---

About the text:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("center-2")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

outputs

> Make money by Selling items on Amazon Selling On Amazon Sell your
>   items on Amazon.com. Amazon can help you grow your business and reach
>   more customers.

If you want to get the three things independently, use e.g.:

```
String headline = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#center-2 .headline")).getText();
System.out.println(headline);

String link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#center-2 .link")).getText();
System.out.println(link);

String body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#center-2 .body")).getText();
System.out.println(body);
```